# iOS - Change UILabel font size proportionally

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoa-touch, autolayout

I have several `UILables` in my view like this:

[image]

Those in red colour should never change their font size. Two others in white colour (50 and 50) should decrease their font size proportionally to fit the content.
What I want to achieve is when any of white labels becomes two big the other should start decreasing in size as well:

[image]

but instead I get this:

[image]

How can I make my UILabels' font size to resize proportionally?

Comment: //Get the Label font size 
CGFloat fontSize = self.label.font.pointSize;

Use this font size for second label

Comment: try [TTTAttributedLabel](https://github.com/mattt/TTTAttributedLabel)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest possible way is as below:

1. Identify the max possible widths of label 1 and label2.
2. Sum up widths of both label.
3. Append both the strings which you want to set in both labels.
4. Get the font size that fits given (combined) text in combined width.
5. Now calculate the width of first text for above identified font size and assign it to first label.
6. Adjust rest of the labels frame according to its frame.
7. Similarly identify the width of second label.
8. Assign above derived font size to both labels.

Answer (score 1):

One easy way to do this is by adjusting the fontSize manually using `UILabel's` `sizeToFit` method to calculate its bounds.

```
int fontSize = MAX_FONTSIZE;
BOOL fontSizeNeedsToBeAdjusted = NO;
CGRect originalLabelFrame1 = label1.frame;
CGRect originalLabelFrame2 = label2.frame;

while(fontSizeNeedsToBeAdjusted && fontSize>MIN_FONTSIZE){
    label1.frame = originalLabelFrame1;
    label1.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:fontSize];
    [label1 sizeToFit];

    label2.frame = originalLabelFrame2;
    label2.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:fontSize];
    [label2 sizeToFit];

    if(CGRectGetWidth(label1.frame)>CGRectGetWidth(originalLaeblFrame1) || CGRectGetHeight(label1.frame)>CGRectGetHeight(originalLaeblFrame1)) 
    || CGRectGetWidth(label2.frame)>CGRectGetWidth(originalLaeblFrame2) || CGRectGetHeight(label2.frame)>CGRectGetHeight(originalLaeblFrame2)){
    fontSizeNeedsToBeAdjusted = YES;
    fontSize--;
}else
    fontSizeNeedsToBeAdjusted = NO;
}
```

A quicker way would be calculating the size with `NSString's` `boundingRectWithSize:                                          options:attributes:context:` method:

```
NSDictionary *attributes = @{NSFontAttributeName: [UIFont systemFontofSize:fontSize]};
// NSString class method: boundingRectWithSize:options:attributes:context is
// available only on ios7.0 sdk.
CGRect bounds = [label1.text boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake(CGRectGetWidth(label1.frame), MAXFLOAT)
                                          options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin
                                       attributes:attributes
                                          context:nil];
```

Answer (score 1):

I expected the answer to this is in `NSMutableAttributedString` so i did a small experiment with this

```
NSString *quantity = @"123456";

NSString *metrics =@"m2";

NSString *quantity2 = @"50";

NSString *metrics2 =@"pk";

NSString *separator = @" / ";


NSMutableAttributedString *fullString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString: 
    [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@%@%@%@",quantity,metrics,separator,quantity2,metrics2]];

[fullString addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName
                   value:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:25.0]
                   range:NSMakeRange(quantity.length+metrics.length, separator.length)];

[fullString addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName
            value:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:12.0]
            range:NSMakeRange(fullString.length-metrics.length, metrics.length)];


_lblTitle.attributedText =  fullString;
```

So try changing the values and adding attributes you will get what you want